# how to encrypt password for steam using RSA

Tags: node.js, python-requests

I think who works with requests, met with such a problem as encrypting the steam password using RSA, so I found many solutions to this problem, but in other languages (php, c#), on node.js available for my language was the code:

```
const RSA = require('node-rsa');
var key = new RSA();
key.setOptions({encryptionScheme: ''});
key.importKey({
    n: Buffer.from([[PUBLICKEY_MOD]], 'hex'),
    e: Buffer.from('010001', 'hex')
}, 'components-public');
var crypt = key.encrypt([[PASSWORD]], 'base64');
console.log(crypt);
[[CRYPT]] = crypt;
```

But it does not work, and when using an encrypted password, it gives the error:

> The account name or password that you have entered is incorrect.

This is actually my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do with the `cypto` module in node, example for you:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const { privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 2048
});

const password = 'abc123';
const encrypted = crypto.privateEncrypt(privateKey, Buffer.from(password));

console.log(encrypted.toString('hex'));
```

more detail on [node doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback)